# What issues would you face if you use Nginx

Tags: hosting, nginx

WordPress is quite a memory hog, and I've been thinking of using nginx rather than apache.

The one major consideration before doing that is if there are any plugins which will stop working. I have tested a few and they seem to work, but I need to find out if there are any which might break.

Comment: "...nginx rather than wordpress." Perhaps you mean "nginx rather than Apache"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I unfortnately have no experience with this but evidently it can be done as these articles and plugins address some of the issues:

- [HOWTO: Install WordPress On Nginx](http://elasticdog.com/2008/02/howto-install-wordpress-on-nginx/)
- WordPress + [nginx Compatibility](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nginx-compatibility/) Plugin
- [Howto nginx + wordpress + ubuntu shortest setup](http://joneslee85.wordpress.com/2010/03/13/howto-nginx-wordpress-ubuntu-shortest-setup/)
- [Nginx front-end proxy cache for WordPress](http://hakre.wordpress.com/2010/04/09/nginx-front-end-proxy-cache-for-wordpress/)
- [WordPress Pretty Permalinks with Nginx](http://josephscott.org/archives/2010/06/wordpress-pretty-permalinks-with-nginx/)
- [WordPress, Nginx and WP Super Cache](http://ocaoimh.ie/wordpress-nginx-wp-super-cache/)

Also are you familiar with [WP Engine WordPress hosting](http://wpengine.com)? They are evidently using it in a hybrid form with Apache, probably as a front-end proxy.

- [Back in Startup Mode… Announcing WP Engine!](http://technosailor.aaronbrazell.com/2010/07/29/back-in-startup-mode-announcing-wp-engine/)

Hope these help.

Comment: Thanks for the links Mike. I've tried a number of plugins with it and it seems to work great!

Answer (score 2):

Small world :). You won't see a lot of issues with Nginx and Apache + Wordpress. We use it for our company as well, and we have no problem getting one server to serve 200k uniques/month and over a million pageviews/month for one site. Nginx + W3 Total Cache, you get some very remarkable numbers.

Comment: Yeah :) Thanks for the update. I've been trying it out myself and looks quite solid!

Answer (score 1):

The biggest difference is rewrite rules, but there are plenty of guides out there (such as the ones Mike linked) that provide you with equivalent rewrite rules.

From a plugin perspective, unless the plugin is doing something **really** crazy, then it shouldn't know the difference. All internal rewrite rules and that sorta stuff is handled at the WordPress level, independently of your HTTPD.

In short, go for it.

Comment: Thanks Viper. I got a lot of samples of nginx rules to replace the ones for apache. Besides, have been trying writing Nginx's rules myself, and it seems pretty straight forward. So this shouldn't be an issue anymore.

Comment: https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx#URL_Rewrites_.2F_Permalinks - Since version 3.7, WordPress works with nginx.

Answer (score 1):

Using Nginx will not make Wordpress use less memory. If you're concerned about memory, you can save some server-wise by optimizing your Apache configuration to only load the modules you need and do other configuration that will reduce the memory apache needs.

Next to that, Apache has caching modules as well worth to consider, so to save all memory WordPress would have used when invoked. Since WordPress output get's cached, Wordpress does not need to run any longer and you save the memory.

Comment: @Krzysiek Dróżdż: You added typos, but you didn't fix them. Names in English have uppercase only on the first letter. Everything else is doing vendor marketing which is not professional in technical writing.

Comment: There is no such thing as "Wordpress". The software we are talking about is called "WordPress" - this is trademark and it's the only proper way to spell it. (If you have some other idea, just take a look at how this site is called ;) ).

Comment: See, this is the difference between using a noun or repeating the marketing of some vendor. And for the proper way to spell it, ask your English teacher/tutor first probably if you're looking for a second opinion. And about the trademark, I suggest you take a look into the trademark database first, which marks have been registered exactly... .

Comment: If you use WordPress, you should spell it correctly - and the proper way is WordPress (that's how this software is called). Take a look at the title of this site - is it "Wordpress Answers" or "WordPress Answers"? Also take a look at this poll (http://www.wptavern.com/do-you-mistrust-a-company-that-misspells-wordpress).

Comment: Well, I don't know you, but generally I would say it's not wrong to use English language properly. That's nothing wrong. Everything else might be wanted by Mark Mullenweg (as of he dreams of and that's fine), however I'm not under dictate by him telling me what is wrong or right. So thanks, I'm okay with using my brain myself, you don't need to invest more time to "correct" things here.

Comment: Whatever. Write it as you wish, if you're smarter than everyone else...

Comment: It's not about smarter, it's what you want to follow: Just standard English grammar, or vendor sprak. That's basically all. Following vendor sprak leads technically to typos. That's all that I was saying.

Comment: So why do you follow this vendor sprak on your blog? You use "WordPress", "GitHub", etc. very often there... ;)

Comment: Well the first is a problem with the Wordpress software itself, the second is due to inattention probably.

Comment: @hakre Capitalising trademarked words as exactly as they were registered is widely accepted as correct. Your edits & comments are pedantry.

Answer (score 0):

When WordPress detects that mod_rewrite is not loaded it falls back to pathinfo ie:(/index.php/%postname%/) permalinks in Permalink Settings page. You can use the [nginx Compatibility](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/nginx-compatibility/)plugin to force WordPress to use pretty permalinks then add rewrite rules to your nginx server file:

```
server { server_name mysite.com;

root /path/to/blog;

index index.php;

location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ @wordpress;
}

location @wordpress {
    fastcgi_pass ...;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_NAME /index.php;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    try_files $uri @wordpress;
    fastcgi_index index.php;
    fastcgi_pass ...;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
}

}
```

Comment: [This was fixed in WordPress 3.7, which supports nginx](https://codex.wordpress.org/Nginx#URL_Rewrites_.2F_Permalinks).

Answer (score 0):

The docs are written in Russian and somewhat vague.  Sometimes you're wondering if the translation is bad or if the docs are just not very explicit in the first place.  So finding answers is sometimes time-consuming and/or requires trial-and-error testing.

However, the author seems very engaged with the community, explaining configuration options.  And NginX itself gives you some feedback, such as "you can't use this option here."

Comment: Four years later, Nginx has excellent documentation in English at http://wiki.nginx.org, and there's a [special page on Nginx and WordPress](http://wiki.nginx.org/WordPress).

Answer (score 0):

[I have done research for Ngnix, varnish caching enabled wordpress setup.](http://gotechnies.com/wordpress-installation-nginx-varnish-caching/)

Nginx Virtualhost configuration for wordpress.

```
server {
        listen 127.0.0.1:8080 default_server;
        listen [::]:8080 default_server;
         root /var/www/html/wordpress;
        index index.php index.html index.htm;
        server_name yourdomain.com www.yourdomain.com;
        location / {
                        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php?$args;
                }
         location ~ \.php$ {
                                fastcgi_pass unix:/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
                                fastcgi_index index.php;
                                fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
                                fastcgi_param PATH_INFO $fastcgi_path_info;
                                include fastcgi_params;
                            }
}
```

Install varnish open file /etc/default/varnish, configure like below.

```
DAEMON_OPTS="-a :80 \
             -T localhost:6082 \
             -f /etc/varnish/default.vcl \
             -S /etc/varnish/secret \
             -s malloc,256m"
```

Check the running port.

```
netstat -ntulp
```

if netstat command not found.

```
sudo apt-get install -y net-tools
```

Comment: Can you explain as how it helps OP, just giving link and posting the some answer is not good.

Comment: Given the same answer with link has been posted in multiple places, I am flagging this as spam.